# Broadcasting + reshaping VS list comprehension speed in python

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, array-broadcasting

Given the following `numpy` arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
import time

v1 = np.linspace(20, 250, 100000000)
a = np.array([12.592,16.320])
m = np.array([3, 5])
```

How is it possible that list comprehension:

```py
start = time.time()
v2 = np.max(
    [10 ** _a * np.power(v1.astype(float), -_m) for _m, _a in zip(m, a)],
    axis=0
)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)  # prints 5.822041034698486
```

is more than twice as fast than `numpy`'s [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)?

```py
start = time.time()
v2 = np.max(
    np.power(10, a) * np.power(v1.astype(float)[:, None], -m).reshape(
        v1.shape[0],-1),
    axis=1
)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)  # prints 12.292157173156738
```

And what is the "fastest approach" of calculating `v2`?

Comment: ``zip(m, a)`` has only two elements to iterate. Yes, loops are slow, no they aren't *that* slow. There isn't much to gain by "broadcasting" over such a small space.

Comment: Note: On my system the two are roughly the same speed. 8.37 for the list comprehension, 8.51 for the broadcast.

Comment: Sometimes a few loops on a complex expression are faster than the full broadcasted version, especially if the arrays are large (as in your `v1` case).  Memory management becomes more complex with really large arrays.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj and @MisterMiyagi. In fact reducing the size of `v1` makes broadcasting quicker than list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both are inefficient**. Indeed, you can rewrite the operation much more efficiently using **mathematical property** of the natural logarithm and the exponential. Here is an equivalent (unoptimized) expression that can be further optimized:

```py
v2 = np.max(
    [np.exp(_a * np.log(10) - _m * np.log(v1.astype(float))) for _m, _a in zip(m, a)],
    axis=0
)
```

Since `np.log(v1.astype(float)))` is a constant, you can **pre-compute** it. Actually, `v1` items are already of type `float` (note that `float` means `np.float64` for Numpy and not the CPython `float` object type). `np.log(v1)` will do the job correctly (unless `v1` is set to an array of `np.float32` for example). Additionally, `np.exp` can be computed only on the final result (ie. after computing `np.max`) since `a < b` is equivalent to `e**a < e**b`. Finally, you can use **in-place** operations to avoid creating several expensive **temporary arrays**. This can be done using the `out` parameter of many functions like `np.subtract` or `np.multiply` for example.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
log_v1 = np.log(v1)
tmp = np.empty((len(a), v1.size), dtype=np.float64)
v2 = np.exp(np.max(
    [np.subtract(_a * np.log(10), np.multiply(log_v1, _m, out=_tmp), out=_tmp) for _m, _a, _tmp in zip(m, a, tmp)],
    axis=0, 
    out=tmp[0]
), out=tmp[0])
```

For even faster performance, you can simply use **Numba** so to avoid writing huge array in memory (which is slow). Numba can also use **multiple threads** to speed this up a lot. Here is an example:

```py
import numba as nb

# Note that fastmath=True can cause issues with values likes NaN Inf.
# Please disable it if your input array contains such spacial values.
@nb.njit('float64[::1](float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1])', fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def compute(v1, m, a):
    assert a.size > 0 and a.size == m.size
    out = np.empty(v1.size, dtype=np.float64)
    log10 = np.log(10)
    for i in nb.prange(v1.size):
        log_v1 = np.log(v1[i])
        maxi = a[0] * log10 - m[0] * log_v1
        for j in range(1, len(a)):
            value = a[j] * log10 - m[j] * log_v1
            if value > maxi:
                maxi = value
        out[i] = np.exp(maxi)
    return out

v2 = compute(v1, m.astype(float), a)
```

---

### Benchmark

Here are results on my 6-core machine:

```
Initial code with big arrays:    10.013 s    (inefficient)
Initial code with lists:          8.147 s    (inefficient)
Optimized Numpy code:             2.009 s    (memory-bound)
Optimized Numba code:             0.300 s    (compute-bound)
```

As you can see, **Numba is much faster** than the other methods: about **30 times faster**.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jérôme Richard! `numba` is exactly the solution for my problem!